# Sencha Touch 2: How to reference self in class definition

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am defining a class but am havign trouble trying to reference itself in the code below.  You can see I am trying to sue the push and pop actions but this.self.pop() for example is not the correct way to reference the class.  What is the correct way to reference this in the class definition?

```
//create the navigation view and add it into the Ext.Viewport
Ext.define('myApp.view.Settings', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    id:'view',
    xtype: 'navigationview',
    config: {
        title: 'Settings',
        iconCls: 'settings',
        //we only give it one item by default, which will be the only item in the 'stack' when it loads
        items: [
            {
                //items can have titles
                title: 'Navigation View',
                padding: 10,

                //inside this first item we are going to add a button
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Push another view!',
                        handler: function () {
                            //when someone taps this button, it will push another view into stack
                            this.self.push({
                                //this one also has a title
                                title: 'Second View',
                                padding: 10,

                                //once again, this view has one button
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'button',
                                        text: 'Pop this view!',
                                        handler: function () {
                                            //and when you press this button, it will pop the current view (this) out of the stack
                                            this.self.pop();
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            });
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `this` in the `handler`, `this` will refer to the button, and not the view. If you want to get the `Ext.navigation.View` component, and utilize the push and pop methods, use [Ext.getCmp(id)](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext-method-getCmp):

```
Ext.getCmp('NavView').push(newView); // Instead of this.self.push()
Ext.getCmp('NavView').pop();         // Instead of this.self.pop();
```

Your button handler may look like the following

```
handler: function() {
    var self = Ext.getCmp('NavView');
    var button = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'Pop View',
        id: 'button2',
        handler: function() {
            self.pop();
        }
    });
    var newView = {
        title: 'New View',
        id: 'NewView',
        items: [button]
    };
    self.push(newView);
}
```

[Check out this working example.](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#UXCdX#T6iL7)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `up` method to find a parent container.

```
this.up('navigationview').push(...);
```

Read more here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Button-method-up.